# After fresh install cannot get wifi to work with intel 8265

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, network-interface

This all takes place immediately after a fresh arch install where wifi-menu was working while installing on a Lenovo yoga 720 15ibk. After enabling and starting NetworkManager, wifi-menu returns,

```
-bash: wifi-menu: command not found
```

When I run `rfkill list` I see two Bluetooth devices and no network devices. Running ispci -k and looking in the network controller section shows

```
Netwwork Controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev78)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
Kernal Modules: iwlwifi
```

It does not show kernel driver in use and I am not sure how to set that driver to work as `modprobe iwlwifi` does seemingly nothing.

This article seems to be about the same issue I have but I don't understand what it is saying to do. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=164764&p=2

Any magical lines?

Comment: The article you're referencing basically says that the kernel should recognize the hardware since 3.10. But the article also says, that it's possible to disable the wifi card in the BIOS. Did you check that it's enabled?

Answer (score 1):

`wifi-menu` won't be there if you don't install it manually. From your problem it seems you forgot to install `linux-firmware`.

Recently arch linux has changed a bit, you need to do

```bsh
pacstrap /mnt base linux linux-firmware
```

In your case you have to boot into live media again and install them.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to check that you have the network card active, this you can do with `ifconfig` and `ip addr`.

If the network interface appears (they're usually called `wlp4s0` or `wlan0`) the drivers should be correctly installed; you can corroborate that with `nmcli dev wifi list` or `nmcli dev wifi connect $SSID password $PASS`.

If your WiFi card interfaces do not appear, during installation you must add to `pacstrap` the packages `linux` and `linux-firmware`.

Before:

```
pacstrap /mnt base base-devel networkmanager [...]
```

Now:

```
pacstrap /mnt linux linux-firmware base base-devel networkmanager [...]
```

If you don't want to install the system again no problem, you can try installing the `linux-firmware` package with `pacman` or use the installation disk to mount `/boot` and `/` or add it manually with `pacstrap`, something like that:

```
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
pacstrap /mnt linux-firmware
reboot
```